# Not giving a perfect linear regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am trying to draw a linear regression by scikit module, but it is giving the wrong regression.

```
x=b[['year']]
y=b['pf_score']
l=LinearRegression().fit(x,y)
plt.plot(x,y,'bx')
plt.plot(x,l.coef_*x+l.intercept_,'r-')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to not use the coefficients of the linear regression-model directly. Its better to use the functions that are provided. Something like this should work:

```py
    x = b[['year']]
    y = b['pf_score']
    l = LinearRegression().fit(x,y)
    plt.scatter(x, y, 'bx')
    plt.plot(x, l.predict(x), color='blue', linewidth=3)
    plt.show()
```

You can find more information on the [Linear Regression Example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html) by scikit-learn.